# ZIP command causes in BASH Script zip warning: name not matched

Tags: linux, bash

in a script this

```
(cd "$amdir/archive" && zip -rm "$amdir/archive/a.zip" "$amdir/archive/*")
```

causes zip warning: name not matched

when I echo that and copy paste it to a command line it works fine
any idea why that doesn't work in a bash script on linux ?

Comment: Why do you have asterisk inside double-quotes? `"$amdir/archive/*"` should be `"$amdir/archive/"*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already in `$amdir/archive` after your `cd`.

So your zip tries to find another directory `$amdir/archive`, when already being there.

I can reproduce the error message, when I try to do a `zip -rm` on a nonexisting directory.

In addition you should consider the remark from Inian: by quoting the `*` you escape it and therefore have no bash pattern matching - see for example [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)

So the second part should simply read:

`zip -rm a.zip *`

Comment: thanks a lot the last bit even works inside a bash script